# How to find a generating function in simple, closed form

Tags: generating-functions

I’m stuck on something in [generating functionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf). The first problem asks:
Find the ordinary power series generating functions of the sequence in simple closed form for the sequence $a_n = n$. The sequence is defined as $n ≥ 0$.

I figured out how to get to $A(x) = x/((1-x)^2)$. That’s not an issue.

However, the book lists the answer as $(xD)(1/(1-x)) = x/((1-x)^2)$

Where did the D come from? How can I get my answer in terms of D?

Comment: The $D$ is a differential operator.

Comment: $D$ is $\frac d{dx}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should think of "$xD$" as an operator. "$xD$" read right to left means differentiate and then multiply by $x$. So
$$
(xD)\frac{1}{1-x}=x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)'=x\times\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{x}{1-x^2}.
$$
Note that if
$$
B(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n z^n
$$
then $(xD)B$ is the ogf which corresponds to the sequence $(nb_n)_0^\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
A(x)&=&0+1\cdot x+2\cdot x^2+3\cdot x^3+\cdots\\
&=&x(1+2x+3x^2+\cdots)\\
&=&x\frac{d}{dx}(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)\\
&=&x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\\
&=&\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{eqnarray}